# html output from a django manytomany field with for

Tags: django

i have a many to many relationship like in this model

```
class A(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class B(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   bla = models.ManyToManyField ('A')
```

now i would like to output all relationships in the html
I have a view like:

```
def showview(request):
   b = B().objects.all()
   return render(request, '/bla.html', {'b': b})
```

and the html like:

```
{% for ab in b %}
    b.name
    {% for a in ab.bla %}
        a.name
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

but i get the error?

'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable

I see the entries in the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get all the M2M fields you can do it like:

```
for ab in b.objects.all():
    for a in ab.bla.all():
        print(a.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change B() -B

```
def showview(request):
   b = B().objects.all()
   return render(request, '/bla.html', {'b': b})
```

TO

```
def showview(request):
   b = B.objects.all()
   return render(request, '/bla.html', {'b': b})
```

And in your templates use it like this

```
{% for ab in b %}
    {% for a in ab.bla.all %}
        <p>a</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```